# How to make request in jq

Tags: json, linux, logging, jq, metrics

I'm trying to make request in jq:

```
cat testfile.txt | jq 'fromjson | select(.kubernetes.pod.memory.usage.bytes != null) .kubernetes.pod.memory.usage.bytes, ."@timestamp"'
```

My output is:

```
"2019-03-15T00:24:21.733Z"
"2019-03-15T00:25:10.169Z"
"2019-03-15T00:24:47.908Z"
105889792
"2019-03-15T00:25:04.446Z"
34557952
"2019-03-15T00:25:04.787Z"
```

How to delete excess dates?
For example output only:

```
105889792
"2019-03-15T00:25:04.446Z"
34557952
"2019-03-15T00:25:04.787Z"
```

Comment: What is an “excess date”? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I mean don't output timestamp where is .kubernetes.pod.memory.usage.bytes = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a pipe after select :

```
cat testfile.txt | jq 'fromjson | select(.kubernetes.pod.memory.usage.bytes != null) | .kubernetes.pod.memory.usage.bytes, ."@timestamp"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a DRYer (as in [dry](/questions/tagged/dry)) solution:

```
.["@timestamp"] as $ts | .kubernetes.pod.memory.usage.bytes // empty | ., $ts
```

Note that this particular use of `//` assumes that you wish to treat `null`, `false`, and a missing key in the same way. If not, you can still use the same idea to stay DRY.